# My ListView.Builder doesn't build anything and shows empty screen

Tags: flutter, listview

I am making a list of local songs in the SD card and i get them successfully but whenever i try to put them in a `ListView.Builder` it doesn't show anything on the screen

here is my code for the `ListView.Builder`

```
 @override Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return SingleChildScrollView(
      physics: ScrollPhysics(),
      child: ListView.builder(
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: songsData.songsCount,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return CustomCard(
            songName: songsData.songsList[index].title ??
                Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
            artistName: songsData.songsList[index].artist ??
                Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
          );
        },
      )
  );
[![Screenshot of the output][1]][1]}
```

The function i call to get data already has data in it but the `ListView.Builder` doesn't show them
here is my function code for getting songs list from local storage

```
void getSongsData() async {
songsList = await audioQuery.getSongs();
print(songsList.length);
}
```

the print statements show that there are data in the list >>

```
I/flutter (24671): 332
```

Comment: Try: itemCount: songsData.songsList.length,

Comment: songsData.songsCount is a getter in the SongsData class that gets the songsList.length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list was used in another class which gets data (SongsData) and to read it's length or it's contents it have to be a static list to be accessible by other classes

Answer (score 1):

Try calling setState or using a FutureBuilder.

Comment: setState in the ListView.Builder inside the CustomCard() or where?

Comment: Before print() in getSongsData()

Comment: and write what in it can you explain more?